# Using get_file_contents() to make an array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am trying to upload a CSV file and get it's contents into an array, but I am getting this an  error: (Multiples of this error on each line after 10)

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon\upload_file.php on line 10
```

Below is a sample of my code:

```
if ($handle = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {

$data = array();

while ($csv = array(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]))) {
    $data = array(
        'order-id' => $csv[0],
        'order-item-id' => $csv[1], //This is line 10.
        'purchase-date' => $csv[2],
        'payments-date' => $csv[3],
```

Comment: What is the contents of csv file?

Comment: Tiny code review ... `while ($csv = array(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]))) {` ... wtf?!

Comment: @jack your post is informative. Constructive criticism is beneficial to the op.

Comment: @DarylGill Not sure what you're trying to see. It sounds positive ... :)

Comment: @jack your "wtf" doesn't explain whats actually ment to be improved?

Comment: @DarylGill Isn't that why I've also added an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file()` opens puts each as an array element. `fgetcsv()` and its family of functions are very useful when dealing with csv files.

Your code `array(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]))` will only ever have one element because file_get_contents returns a string.

Comment: Wasn't awware file_get_contents() on returned a string. I was trying to use fgetcsv() at one point but I was having issues with it too. I'll try it again and see where I can get. Thanks!

Comment: @PraveenKumar I didn't downvote you - but you're wrong to suggest exploding by comma for a csv file is a good idea.

Comment: @MikeB May be. Thanks. Will update the code. What do you suggest?

Comment: We both said it, fgetcsv properly handles the delimiter and quoted text.

Comment: @PraveenKumar You can tell if someone downvoted your answer (there are only two and you have a suspect) ... so stop being so touchy.

Comment: Guys, please. :) Leave the downvoting issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

#### This issue comes if your file has only one line.

I guess you need to do this.

```
$row = explode(",", $csv[0]);
$data = array(
    'order-id' => $fileArray[0],
    'order-item-id' => $row[1], //This is line 10.
    'purchase-date' => $row[2],
    'payments-date' => $row[3]
);
```

Also, you can use functions like [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to parse your CSV file.